# How to just check for input once, and not get hung up waiting for the input

Tags: c, arrays, input, uart, mbed

So I am programming with the mbed compiler and this is currently my code.

```
pc.baud(9600);
dev1.baud(19200);
char command[5];
//pc.puts("Initialized1X\n");
//while(1) {
if (1) {
    dev1.gets(command, 6); //this is causing my error...just waiting for command, must fix
    if (command[0] != 0x68){
        for (int x=0; x<4; x++){
            command[x] = command[x+1];
        }
        command[4] = 0x16;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            pc.printf("%x ", command[i]);
    }
        pc.printf("\n");
    sampleRates = command[2];    
    if (command[1] == 0x01){    
        switch (sampleRates){
            case 0x01: pc.printf("44.1k\n");
            return; 
            case 0x02: pc.printf("48k\n");
            return;
            case 0x03: pc.printf("88.2k\n");
            return;
            case 0x04: pc.printf("96k\n");
            return;
            case 0x05: pc.printf("176.4k\n");
            return;
            case 0x06: pc.printf("192k\n");
            return;
            case 0x07: pc.printf("352k\n");
            return;
            case 0x08: pc.printf("384k\n");
            return;
            case 0x09: pc.printf("705.6k\n");
            return;
            case 0x10: pc.printf("768k\n");
            return;

        }
    }
}
//}
```

With the dev1.gets(command, 6); I am getting the input from another device.  The code works fine except when I need to add other functions to my program.  The other functions wont run because it just ends up waiting for input on the dev.1gets() command.  Is there any way I could just make it check real quick, accept the input and move on?  Ive used an if statement with dev1.readable(); but then it doesnt take the commands into the array until I do it again since it only entered the loop. Maybe is there a way to check and save at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input data via an interrupt into a buffer.

Probably a good idea to use double buffering and keep a flag that indicates if a particular buffer contains a 'new' 'complete' command
that is waiting to be processed.

The interrupt handler maintains the circular buffer and handles the actual I/O.

have the interrupt handler smart enough to recognize when a complete 'command' has been entered.

When a complete 'command' has been entered, the interrupt sets a flag for the specific buffer, that the main program can look at/reset to determine if a 'command' is available to process.

The above flag needs to be protected so use a mutex or have the main function disable interrupts while reading/resetting the flag.